Windows doesn't recognize ethernet connection via switch to non-Windows device
I have a Windows 11 laptop, and I'm trying to communicate with an embedded system (non-Windows) that communicates via Ethernet.  The laptop and the embedded system are connected through an inexpensive four-port network switch.  The laptop and the embedded system are both configured to use static IPv4 addresses on the same subnet.  The network adapter on the laptop is a USB-C-to-Ethernet adapter.
Windows on the laptop sometimes recognizes the Ethernet connection right away; sometimes it recognizes the connection after several minutes; sometimes it never recognizes the connection.  The tribal knowledge at my company says to reboot the computer if the connection doesn't work.  Sometimes rebooting helps, and sometimes it doesn't.
When the connection is recognized, Windows says that the Ethernet port is connected with no internet connection, and the embedded system can be pinged.  When the connection isn't recognized, the Network Connections settings page says that the Ethernet port isn't connected, and pinging the embedded system fails.
Unfortunately I can't see what's happening on the embedded system; when I can ping the embedded system the test software works, and when I can't ping the embedded system, my test software shows a spinning circle.
The network engineer inside me wants to run Wireshark to see what the difference in the traffic is between a successful session and an unsuccessful one, but I don't have two work days to brute-force the problem.
Can anyone give me any tips to get Windows to recognize the ethernet connection?  Maybe a specific procedure for powering the switch, powering the embedded system, and connecting the ethernet cable to the laptop?  Or even better, a command to force Windows to connect?

Have you checked the usual places : Latest driver for the Windows network adapter, errors in the Event Viewer.

... Instead of rebooting, try to disable and re-enable the network adapter a few times. If it helps, it can be implemented via a ,bat file for simplicity.

Ah, I didn't think of the Event Viewer, since I'm more of a Linux guy these days.  I like the idea to use a batch file or PowerShell script to automate disabling and re-enabling the network adapter. Great suggestions, thanks!

I originally neglected to mention that the network adapter is a USB-C-to-Ethernet adapter. Disabling it and re-enabling it in Windows doesn't work, nor does unplugging and re-plugging the adapter in the USB C jack.  I couldn't find any clues that I understood in the system event log.  However, after nothing else worked, a reboot made it work. Ah, Windows.

From the fact that you don't need to restart the switch & router, I would say they aren't to blame. Windows might not be to blame - my money would be on a flaky adapter confusing Windows. One more try when it happens: In Device Manager, select the "Network adapters" branch, in Action menu choose "Scan for hardware changes" and see if it detects something.

When the problem happens I can plug and unplug the USB-C-to-Ethernet adapter, and it appears and disappears in the Device Manager, but still refuses to connect until I reboot.  I tried to connect to the same switch from a different Windows 11 laptop with a built-in Ethernet jack and had no trouble.  So my money's with you @harrymc, I think the USB-C-to-Ethernet adapter is just flaky. Thanks!

From the fact that you don't need to restart the switch or the router,
I would say they aren't to blame. Windows might not be to blame either - my
money would be on a flaky adapter confusing Windows.
One test you could do is when it happens, in Device Manager, select
the "Network adapters" branch, and in Action menu choose
"Scan for hardware changes", to see if the adapter just dropped out
of sight for a short time. This hardware detection is also done by
Windows when booting.
When the problem happens the poster can plug and unplug the
USB-C-to-Ethernet adapter, and it appears and disappears in the
Device Manager, but still refuses to connect until reboot.
Connecting to the same switch from a different Windows 11 laptop
with a built-in Ethernet jack had no trouble.
I believe that problem is solely with the USB-C-to-Ethernet adapter.

Another possibility in this vein: Check in Windows Device Manager if the driver for  the NIC has a PowerManagement tab. If so DISABLE power-management for this NIC. In my experience over 90% of weird network issues in Windows is either due to a bad/flaky driver or Windows putting the NIC to sleep at the wrong moment (or a combination of both).


Windows on the laptop sometimes recognizes the Ethernet connection right away; sometimes it recognizes the connection after several minutes
When the connection isn't recognized, the Network Connections settings page says that the Ethernet port isn't connected,

That has nothing to do with your other device, as the Ethernet link is established to the switch, not through the switch. On modern switched Ethernet, there is no shared bus anymore – each cable is a completely independent point-to-point connection.
So I would first suggest changing the Ethernet cable, then changing the switch (to a different model, even if they're all the same chip inside), then changing the laptop's Ethernet interface (get a USB Ethernet dongle just to see if it works), and then changing the whole laptop. The laptop's Ethernet NIC drivers could also have an effect (sometimes a much newer version is available as an "optional update").
(It could be, in theory, that the other device is influencing the behavior of the switch somehow – I've had even managed rackmount switches crash just from a certain device rebooting while connected – but this doesn't change that "port isn't connected" is still entirely between your laptop and your switch.)
It might be worth trying to exchange a Gigabit switch for an 100 Mbps-only one or vice versa, as the two modes work very differently. (It's possible to partially fry an Ethernet port so that 10/100 Mbps links work perfectly fine but 1 Gbps mode doesn't work at all. And on the other hand, a cable with mixed-up pairs may run "fine" in 1 Gbps mode but will never work with 10/100 Mbps ports.)

The network engineer inside me wants to run Wireshark to see what the difference in the traffic is between a successful session and an unsuccessful one, but I don't have two work days to brute-force the problem.

There is no traffic that Wireshark would see at this point, as the problem is that you don't even have the "lower layer" over which any traffic could be sent. The only traffic you have (if at all) is the link pulses between the two ports and you'd need a signal analyzer to see them.

Aha, I didn't know anything before about the communications and negotiations that happen when two devices are connected by an Ethernet cable. I wonder if one connects a Windows computer to a (properly working) switch that isn't connected to anything else, will Windows say that the Ethernet port is connected? Thanks for the information and suggestions!

Yes, both the PC and the switch would still show that the port is connected at a certain speed, since the switch itself is what terminates the Ethernet connection to each of its ports. That's all inherent in the purpose of a switch as it makes decisions on which port to forward each packet through (i.e. it doesn't simply connect all ports together; that's what differentiates it from an older "hub"). Which is also what allows the mode/speed to be different from port to port – e.g. "PC–switch" can run at 1G while "switch–device" can run at 100M.
